# Firebase Dynamic Link in Snapchat is not working as link attached

Tags: android, ios, firebase, deeplink, snapchat

I use Firebase Dynamic Link in my app to share some profile and another details inside my apps, in apps like facebook or instagram the shared link works perfectly but in snapchat using the link attached function, the page stays in blank.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP48n.jpg)

I generated the dynamic link inside the app and manual (through the web interface) and the same behavior. I tested on Android and IOS.

Regards.

Comment: Tested dynamic link generated: https://bprox.page.link/naxz

Comment: I think the problem is related with chrome conflict using intent: https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/

Comment: by default its working on android and for iOS add $ios_nativelink=true url, check documentation.